# Error with keras model: expected dense_53 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 28, 28)

Tags: python, keras

I have a model and although I have a flatten layer it keeps giving me the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_53 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 28, 28)
```

Additionaly, if I remove the dense and flatten layers it gives me the same error for the maxPooling and then for the convolutional. Here is my entire code:

```
import os 
import numpy as np 
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras import backend as K

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical

PATH = os.getcwd()

train_path = PATH+'/Downloads/KerasStuff/train_data/rice/'
train_batch = os.listdir(train_path)
x_train = np.empty((0,32,32,3))

# if data are in form of images
for sample in train_batch:
 img_path = train_path+sample
 if img_path == '/Users/23athreyad/Downloads/KerasStuff/train_data/rice/.DS_Store':
  print("INVALID")
 else:
  x = image.load_img(img_path)
  np.append(x_train,x)

test_path = PATH+'/Downloads/KerasStuff/test_data/rice/'
test_batch = os.listdir(test_path)
x_test = []

for sample in test_batch:
 img_path = test_path+sample
 x = image.load_img(img_path)
 # preprocessing if required
 x_test.append(x)

# Create the model

K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2),data_format="channels_last"))
print(model.output_shape)
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
print(model.output_shape)
model.add(Dense(7200,activation = 'relu'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size = 10, epochs = 20,callbacks=[EarlyStopping(min_delta=0.001, patience=3)])
```

Can someone help me with this? I am new to Keras and have looked this up but not found any solutions.

Comment: Here's one thing you might do to help us: give each layer a name, and then run it again. That way we can see exactly which layer is causing a problem.

Comment: @CalebH. Could you give an example?

Comment: Sure. Your last line looks like `model.add(Dense(7200,activation = 'relu'))`. Simply change it to `model.add(Dense(7200,activation = 'relu', name="<insert_name_here>"))`

Comment: Then, if that's where the error occured, instead of saying `dense_53` it would say `<insert_name_here>`

Comment: @CalebH. The dense layer is where the problem occured

Comment: That is what it looks like, but it seems as if you have many more dense layers. It says the 53rd dense layer gave the error but I only see one.

Comment: In general the layers are named sequentially, when running a regular Python script the layers are named the same on each execution but when running code over an IPython kernel (on Jupyter for example) the layers are renamed in each execution if the kernel is not restarted, for instance `dense_53` in this case means it's the 53rd execution of a single dense layer model.

Comment: @vlizana So do we know what the error is yet?